# Image of smooth curve containing the image of a point as smooth point

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, projective-varieties

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a finite, surjective morphism of smooth, quasi-projective varieties over a field $k$ of characteristic zero. Let $p\in X$.

If $\dim X>0$, then does there necessarily exist a smooth curve $C$ on $X$ such that $f(p)$ is a smooth point of the closure of $f(C)$ in $Y$ ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something this would seem to fail if X is a smooth blow up of Y at a singular point of Y.

Comment: @aginensky: $Y$ is assumed smooth.

Comment: @ Laurent Moret-Bailly- that's what I get for looking at things first thing in the morning.  I did indeed mis-read !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not true.  Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic prime to $34$.  Let the domain of the morphism be a Zariski open neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{A}^2_k$ with coordinates $(s,t)$.  Let the target of the morphism be a Zariski open neighborhood of the origin in $\mathbb{A}^2$ with coordinates $(u,v)$.  Consider the following quasi-finite morphism, $$f:\mathbb{A}^2\to \mathbb{A}^2, \ \ f^*u = s^3 + t^5, \ f^*v = t^7 +  s^{11}.$$

**Finiteness on appropriate neighborhoods of the origin.** By Bezout's Theorem, the generic degree of this morphism is $5\cdot 11 = 55$.  The fiber over the origin is a complete intersection zero-cycle in the affine plane.  The length of the component supported at the origin is $3\times 7 = 21$.  Since $f^*u$ equals zero on this zero-cycle, the residual zero-cycle has coordinates $(s,t) = (a^5,-a^3)$ for some $a\in k^\times$.  Plugging into $f^*v$, also $a^{34}-1 = 0$.  This has $34$ distinct solutions, and thus the residual has length $34$.  Altogether, the zero-cycle has length $55$.  Thus, this quasi-finite, flat morphism is finite when restricted to an appropriate Zariski open neighborhood of the origin in the target and inverse image Zariski open neighborhood of the origin in the domain.

**Reduction to power series computations.** Consider the origin, $p$, in the domain.  Every smooth arc of a curve at $C$ is either (Case I) the graph of a function $t=q(s)$ for $q\in sk[[s]]$, or (Case II) the graph of a function $s=r(t)$ for $r\in tk[[t]].$

**Case I.**  The case $q(s)=0$ gives an arc $f(s) = (s^3,s^{11})$, which is a hypercusp.  Thus, $q(s)$ is not identically zero.  Therefore $q(s)$ has a power series expansion, $$q(s) = cs^m(1+sw(s)), \ \ c\neq 0, \ m\geq 1, \  w(s)\in k[[s]].$$  This gives, $$f^*u(s,q(s)) = s^3(1+c^5s^{5m-3}(1+sw(s))^5), \ \ f^*v(s,q(s)) = c^7s^{7m}(1+sw(s))^7 + s^{11}.$$  If this is the composition of a ramified morphism of smooth curves, $$\phi:C\to D,$$ followed by an immersion, $$\iota:D\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2,$$ then $\iota^*u$ must be a local coordinate on $D$.  Thus, $\iota^*v$ must be a power series in $\iota^*u$, say $$\iota^*v = b(\iota^*u)^n + ... , \ \ b\neq 0.$$  Pulling back this identity by $\phi$ gives the identity, $$c^7s^{7m}(1+sw(s))^7 + s^{11} = bs^{3n}(1+c^5s^{5m-3}(1+sw(s))^5)^n + ...$$  If $m$ equals $1$, the lowest power of $s$ with nonzero coefficient on the left-hand side is $7$, and this is not a multiple of $3$.  If $m\geq 2$, the lowest power is $11$, and this is also not a multiple of $3$.  Thus, Case I leads to a contradiction.

**Case II.**  The case $r(t)=0$ gives an arc $f(t) = (t^5,t^{7})$, which is a hypercusp.  Thus, $r(t)$ is not identically zero.  Therefore $r(t)$ has a power series expansion, $$r(t) = ct^m(1+tw(t)), \ \ w(t)\in k[[s]].$$  If $m$ equals $1$, then $r(t)$ is a formal isomorphism, and we can find an inverse function $t=q(s)$.  By Case I, this leads to a contradiction.  Therefore, $m$ is at least $2$.

This gives, $$f^*u(r(t),t) = t^5(1+c^3s^{3m-5}(1+tw(t))^3), \ \ f^*v(r(t),t) = t^7 + c^{11}t^{11m}(1+tw(t))^{11}.$$  If this is the composition of a ramified morphism of smooth curves, $$\phi:C\to D,$$ followed by an immersion, $$\iota:D\hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}^2,$$ then $\iota^*u$ must be a local coordinate on $D$.  Thus, $\iota^*v$ must be a power series in $\iota^*u$, say $$\iota^*v = b(\iota^*u)^n + ... , \ \ b\neq 0.$$  Pulling back this identity by $\phi$ gives the identity, $$t^7 + c^{11}t^{11m}(1+tw(t))^{11} = bt^{5n}(1+c^3t^{3m-5}(1+tw(t))^3)^n + ...$$  The lowest power of $t$ on the left-hand side is $7$.  Since $7$ is not a multiple of $5$, this is a contradiction in Case II.

Therefore, there is no smooth arc of a curve $C$ at $p$ such that the restriction of $f$ to $C$ factors as a ramified morphism of smooth curves followed by an immersion..